# Using a func parameter returns IEnumerable instead of IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iqueryable

I've minimised my issue to this:

I have a `DbContext` with a `DbSet<PageBlock>` and I get an `IQueryable` with a simple LINQ "Where" like so:

```
IQueryable<PageBlock> result = _context.PageBlocks.Where(x => x.PageId == 2);
```

But if I wrap this line in a method and pass a `Func<PageBlock, bool>` to the method for the where clause like this:

```
private IQueryable<PageBlock> GetQueryable(Func<PageBlock, bool> belongsToPage)
{
    IQueryable<PageBlock> result = _context.PageBlocks.Where(belongsToPage);
    ...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var result = GetQueryable(x => x.PageId == 2)
```

then the `.Where` now returns an `IEnumerable` and I get a compile error!? The IDE says I can put an explicit `cast` on like this:

```
IQueryable<PageBlock> result =
    IQueryable<PageBlock>)_context.PageBlocks.Where(belongsToPage);
```

but that gives a runtime error

> ``` Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator``1[DAL.Models.PageBlock]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable``1[DAL.Models.PageBlock]'. ```

Why does using the same filter indirectly via the Func param cause my query to return `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable` ?!

Comment: Try _context.PageBlocks.Where(belongsToPage).AsQueryable()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in the `IQueryable` world then everything in your query has to be executed via EntityFramework in your database. However what the C# compiler sees is that you want to use and call an arbitrary function. The only way it make that work is to enumerate the query so far and call that function on every returned value. It doesn't matter that your specific function could be executed by the database.

If you want to call your method like this `var result = GetQueryable(x => x.PageId == 2)` you should mimic the signature of `Queriable.Where` and accept an `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate` as your argument.

```
private IQueryable<PageBlock> GetQueryable(Expression<Func<PageBlock, bool>> belongsToPage)
{
    IQueryable<PageBlock> result = _context.PageBlocks.Where(belongsToPage);
    ...
}
```

That way the query provider can examin the expression and see if it can be passed to the database

Comment: AHhh nice. I was just reading about QueryProviders but it was all over my head - this has put a lot of it into some context! THanks!